# wordpress - how to exclude category from foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, categories

i have this filter categories function on my wordpress theme-functions.php file:

```
function tie_categories_filter() {
    if( tie_get_option( 'enable_filter' ) && tie_get_option( 'on_home' ) == 'grid' ):
        $exc_home_cats = tie_get_option( 'exc_home_cats' );
        if( $exc_home_cats )
            $comma_cats_separated = @implode(",", $exc_home_cats );
        $categories = get_categories('exclude='.$comma_cats_separated); ?>

<ul id="filters">
  <li class="current all-items"><a href="#" data-filter="*"><?php _e( 'All' , 'tie' ) ?></a></li>
  <li class="current all-items"><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_1">General</a></li>

<?php
  foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_<?php echo $category->term_id ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
<?php
    endif;
}
```

i added this line:

```
<li class="current all-items"><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_1">General</a></li>
```

so in the site it shows the "ALL" filter, then "General" and then i want to show the rest of the categories.

so i need to exclude the "General" category from the loop.
i can reach her by wordpress term_id=1,

how can i do this in php?

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest option is to add `if` statement in loop to check if `term_id` is 1. If yes, `continue` loop.

```
<?php
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if ($category->term_id === 1) {
        continue;
    }
?>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".cat_<?php echo $category->term_id ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```